# String To Dictionary with Multiple Values for a Key

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a string `'{"News":"news", "News":"politics", "News":"breaking", "News":"stories"}'` that I am trying to convert to a dictionary. I have used both `json.loads()` and `ast.literal_eval()` to convert them, but it seems like both methods only take the last key value pair.

Is there a one line solution for this problem? Or would I need something more complex?

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: I am aware; is there a way to have this load into one dictionary with "News" as the key and the four separate values loaded?

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? There are certainly ways to parse it that way, but it's not going to be fun/pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries can not have more than one instance for every key. That's why you can not produce a dictionary with 4 identical keys, `News` for that case.

Consider changing the data format to something that meet your specifications, like a dictionary with a list values:

```
{"News": ["news", "politics", "breaking", "stories"]}
```

Comment: I just had this thought as well; probably going to be my solution for the time being.

Comment: Many (most) folks don't have the option of changing the format of the source data, so I don't know how applicable this would be generally.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the string is otherwise valid JSON, you could use the `object_pairs_hook` parameter to the JSON decoder:

```
import json


def multidict(l):
    result = {}
    for k, v in l:
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return result

data = '{"News":"news", "News":"politics", ' \
       '"News":"breaking", "News":"stories"}'
data = json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=multidict)
assert data == {'News': ['news', 'politics', 'breaking', 'stories']}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the [hooks](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dictionary = defaultdict(list)

>>> values = '{"News":"news", "News":"politics", "News":"breaking", "News":"stories"}'
>>> for pair in values.strip('{}').split(','):
...     key, value = pair.strip().split(':')
...     key = key.strip('"')
...     value = value.strip('"')
...     dictionary[key].append(value)
```

Result:

```
>>> dictionary
{'News': ['news', 'politics', 'breaking', 'stories']}
```